# apache resolving urls before looking in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a rewrite rule of the following form:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ foo.php?arg=$1 [qsa,nc]
```

It takes urls of the form `/foo/bar` and changes them to `/foo.php?arg=bar`

It works properly locally, and it works on my old host but I moved to a new host (running ubuntu) and it behaves differently.

On the new host apache notices that there is a foo.php and calls it directly.  In other words, urls of the form `/foo/bar` are seen as `/foo.php`.  If I rename `foo.php` to `foo_junk.php` and change the rewrite rule to be

```
RewriteRule ^foo/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ foo_junk.php?arg=$1 [qsa,nc]
```

Then it all works.  So it's not that I didn't enable overrides or that I failed to install mod_rewrite or anything.  Rewrites work, they're just being done at a different point in the process of resolving a url than they are locally.

Is there a configuration option for this?

Comment: What are the apache version differences between your local box and the new host?

Comment: apache version differences very rarely have that kind of effect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling [`MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews):

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Yep, I've run into that myself. Nasty little side effect.